# Efficiency when populating a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Which would be more efficient, and why?

```
vector<int> numbers;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    numbers.push_back(1);
```

or

```
vector<int> numbers(10,0);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    numbers[i] = 1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest would be:

```
vector <int> numbers(10, 1);
```

As for your two methods, usually the second one; although the first one avoids the first zeroing of the vector in the constructor, it allocates enough memory from the beginning, avoiding the reallocation.

In the benchmark I did some time ago the second method won even if you called `reserve` before the loop, because the overhead of `push_back` (which has to check for each insert if the capacity is enough for another item, and reallocate if necessary) still was predominant on the zeroing-overhead of the second method.

Note that this holds for primitive types. If you start to have objects with complicated copy constructors generally the best performing solution is `reserve` + `push_back`, since you avoid all the useless calls to the default constructor, which are usually heavier than the cost of the `push_back`.

Comment: That would be faster in this case where you want a vector full of ints of the same value. We used to actually find we often wanted to initialize our vectors so each position held its own value. Often used for indexing where you then intend to sort it based on another vector. The fastest way to create that is to have a static array of such values of a certain size and initialize with 2 iterators if yours doesn't exceed the size of the static one.

Answer (score 4):

In general the second one is faster because the first might involve one or more reallocations of the underlying array that stores the data. This can be aleviated with the `reserve` function like so:

```
vector<int> numbers;
numbers.reserve(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    numbers.push_back(1);
```

This would be almost close in performance to your 2nd example since `reserve` tells the vector to allocate enough space for all the elements you are going to add so no reallocations occur in the for loop. However `push_back` still has to check whether vector's size exceeds it's current capacity and increment the value indicating the size of the vector so this will still be slightly slower than your 2nd example.

Comment: Actually in a benchmark I noticed that, with primitive types, `reserve`+`push_back` was still beaten by direct access, probably because `push_back` does not only have to increment the end pointer, but also has to check if there's enough space left for another item.

Answer (score 2):

In general, probably the second, since `push_back()` may cause reallocations and resizing as you proceed through the loop, while in the second instance, you are pre-sizing your vector.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is faster because of preallocation of memory. In the first variant of code you could also use `numbers.reserve(10);` which will allocate some memory for you at once, and not at every iteration (maybe some implementation does more bulky reservation, but don't rely on this).

Also you'd better use iterators, not straight-forward access. Because iterator operation is more predictable and can be easely optimized.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

staitc const size_t N_ELEMS = 10;

void some_func() {
  vector<int> numbers(N_ELEMS);

  // Verbose variant
  vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin();
  while(it != numbers.end())
    *it++ = 1;


  // Or more tight (using C++11 lambdas)
  // assuming vector size is adjusted
  generate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), []{ return 1; });
}


//
```

Comment: Actually, for `vector`s iterators and direct access should be the same, since `operator[]` is completely inlined, so it should just be just one assembly instruction more (the `add` between the start of the vector and the index). By the way, in your loop you could just write `it!=numbers.end()` and get rid of `i`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia you are right about `i`, I'll correct this, thanks) But as for `operator[]`, there are some instructions like `rep movs`. Those not usefull in this case (when filling from generator), but when copying.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second, and if you have [iota](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iota.html) available (C++11 has it) use that instead of the for loop.

```
std::vector<int> numbers(10);
std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a middle case, where you use `reserve()` then call `push_back()` a lot of times. This is always going to be at least as efficient than just calling `push_back()` if you know how many elements to insert.

The advantage of calling `reserve()` rather than `resize()` is that it does not need to initialise the members until you are about to write to them. Where you have a vector of objects of a class that need construction, this can be more expensive, especially if the default constructor for each element is non-trivial, but even then it is expensive.

The overhead of calling push_back though is that each time you call it, it needs to check the current size against the capacity to see if it needs to re-allocate.

So it's a case of N initializations vs N comparisons. When the type is int, there may well be an optimization with the initializations (memset or whatever) allowing this to be faster, but with objects I would say the comparisons (reserve and push_back) will almost certainly be quicker.